# OpenLayers 6: How to build the library?

Tags: build, openlayers

I'm upgrading an existing project from OL3 to OL6.
That includes some customised extensions to OL which I need to forward port.
What I can't seem to find, is the process to simply rebuild the library from source, to produce the same set of files (with our customisations) as here: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/download/v6.14.1/6.14.1-dist.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the "legacy" ol.js library in npm, use:

```
npm run-script build-legacy
```

(with the correct dependencies, npm, shx; I got the openlayers source by cloning it in git)